# How asp.net mvc3 works behind the scenes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there an article, blog post, or any documentation that explain the functionality of asp.net mvc 3? Something that expose what happens behind the scenes to glue together all the parts that I use on top of the framework.

I need to implement some logic that right now is not supported by default, so I'll have to get my hands dirty and rewrite or extend some of the actors. But i still haven't a bright view of what's happening below.

Comment: Perhaps rather than a very high level question like "How does MVC 3 work" you should be asking how specifically to implement your required changes. Proibably, all you'll need is a different ModelBinder.

Comment: How do you know then that required logic is not supported?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit old, but much of it is still the same: [MVC Pipeline](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/11/20/aspnet-mvc-pipeline-lifecycle/)

Here's an [updated version of the poster](http://ajaxus.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/asp_net_mvc_poster.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-overview-cs

This is what I first started reading

Answer (score 0):

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/TechDays-2011-Belgium/TD013

This talk is about a deep dive into MVC3, might be off help for you.